# Google SEO, how to hide links, text, images from google

Tags: seo

i have some text and links that gets generated and i want to hide it from google. Any ideas?

i don't want to convert them to images. Maybe use some kind of javascript....???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to tell the Google Crawler not to index the content.

Answer (score 0):

login Google webmaster tools and copy that link to you will delete that and in Google webmaster tools open menu and select delete crawler option and after paste your link that remove your link successfully in Google search enginee